# max timestamp of bitcoin transaction on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, bitcoin

When I query the max timestamp on Google BigQuery tables of bitcoin transactions I get the following:

```
select timestamp_millis(max(timestamp)) from `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions` 

+-------+-------------------------+
| Line  | f0_                     | 
+-------+-------------------------+
|     1 | 2018-09-10 13:23:25 UTC |
+-------+-------------------------+
```

However, the table details describes that the last update on that table was December 8th 2018 19:51:43 (2 minutes ago as I write this).

I know that the tables are supposed to be updated every 10 minutes, so why I can't find transactions with timestamps close to the last updates?

Comment: what is your timezone?

Comment: Central US (UTC -6)

Comment: seems google don't update it since 09-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-six-new-cryptocurrencies-in-bigquery-public-datasets-and-how-to-analyze-them) GCP article, the bitcoin public dataset has been moved to a new location along with adding support for several other cryptocurrencies.

Running the equivalent query on the new dataset:

```
SELECT max(block_timestamp) 
FROM 
`bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions`
```

Returns: `2019-04-29 23:59:19 UTC`

The cryptocurrencies that are now supported are:

- Bitcoin
- Bitcoin Cash
- Dash
- Dogecoin
- Ethereum
- Ethereum Classic
- Litecoin
- Zcash